# C# itextsharp working with letterhead

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

i have to merge two pdf files, one is the letterhead (source.pdf) an the other is a code generated pdf page (overlay.pdf). the letterhead can be a scanned or a digital copy. i used the code i found at here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e78ccbbf-3d00-4612-b342-269eb0075982/make-a-pdf-as-a-background-of-another-pdf?forum=csharpgeneral
. My problem is that the text from the overlay.pdf not showing up if the letterhead is scanned, when the letterhead is an digital copy etc. from Photsop it works! BUT the text is there in the output.pdf i can select it.
[output.pdf with invisible text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HIVh.png)
i hope anyone has an idea. thank you

Comment: Hmm... you're using an example that isn't entirely correct. You should use `PdfStamper` with `overlay.pdf` and add `source.pdf` in the background. There is no reason to use `PdfWriter`. Did you take a look at the official documentation? More specifically: http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-superimpose-pages-existing-documents-another-document

Comment: I flagged your answer as "Not an answer." This means that your answer (that is actually a comment) will probably disappear soon.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Java developer, so I am not familiar with all the details of C#. Nevertheless I'm going to try to write some C#. If that code doesn't work immediately, please treat it as if it were pseudo-code. The principles are correct; the syntax may contain errors.

```
// Actual content
PdfReader overlay = new PdfReader("overlay.pdf");
int n = overlay.NumberOfPages;
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(overlay,
    new FileStream("result.pdf", FileMode.Create);
// Company stationery (letter head)
PdfReader stationery = new PdfReader("source.pdf");
PdfImportedPage page = stamper.GetImportedPage(stationery, 1);
// Add stationery page to each page of real content
PdfContentByte background;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
     background = stamper.GetUnderContent(i);
     background.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
}
// Close the stamper
stamper.Close();
```

As I explained in my comment, there is no need to use `PdfWriter`. You just take the existing PDF with the real content, and you add the single-page PDF with the letterhead and you add it to the background.

**Update**

If your `overlay.pdf` is opaque, it is only normal that you won't see `source.pdf` as that content will be covered. In that case, you might consider using transparency:

```
// Actual content
PdfReader overlay = new PdfReader("overlay.pdf");
int n = overlay.NumberOfPages;
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(overlay,
    new FileStream("result.pdf", FileMode.Create);
// Company stationery (letter head)
PdfReader stationery = new PdfReader("source.pdf");
PdfImportedPage page = stamper.GetImportedPage(stationery, 1);
// Add stationery page to each page of real content
PdfContentByte foreground;
PdfGState state = new PdfGState();
state.FillOpacity = 0.6f;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
     foreground = stamper.GetOverContent(i);
     foreground..SaveState();
     foreground.SetGState(state);
     foreground.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
     foreground.RestoreState();
}
// Close the stamper
stamper.Close();
```

This may not be the optimal result. You can try changing the `0.6` fill opacity, but it's the best result you'll get if crazy people give you opaque letter-head PDFs (that's *not done*; people who do this are totally unprofessional).

Comment: Instead of transparency the op might also want to try the blend mode **Darken**. Often this results in better outputs. (Depending on the overlayed content, though, the output may also contain unwanted artifacts. Thus, plex, please really test before using in production.)